# Subwoofer Sound Settings revert back to default when sound level is set to minimum (mute/off), causing blown sub woofer speaker

Tags: sound, settings, volume-control, speakers, output

I am having an annoying and destructive problem with my Subwoofer Sound Settings, it keep reverting back to default when the sound level is set to minimum (mute/off).
This problem has blown my sub-woofer on my Macbook Pro. Before I replace the subwoofer, I would like to see if I could remedy this problem.

Background - At times I need to raise the volume for some shows or movies. I noticed my subwoofer about to explode so I adjusted the Subwoofer level to medium. This helped, BUT, at times I would lower the level and hit the minimum level (basically muting it). Well, Ubuntu eventually blew out my subwoofer. When I went back to these settings, I noticed the subwoofer level was back to the same level as the Output Volume. I also noticed the PROBLEM... if the output volume level hits minimum, this does the same with the subwoofer, and in turn, raising this level also raises the subwoofer in tandem, at times to maximum.
I would like my subwoofer to NEVER exceed the level in which I set it too.

I assume I am not the only one whom has experienced this destructive hardware setting.

Cheers, - Ian

Answer (score 0):

even after allowing ubuntu to delete my Nvidia Driver ... thinking Maybe it was the issue (but still FULLY linked To Ubuntu) ... I let it revert to Nouveau ...
...
then NO SOUND AT ALL! even while displaying all the 7.1 speakers - NOTHING!

Thinking it may be still Nvidia I let Ubuntu (sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall) ... but ... Ubuntu then happily installed the Awesome Nvidia 440.XX)

and still problem persists

So much for Nvidia's fault!